# fluid dynamics - How to understand material derivative?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fluid-dynamics

I'm learning CFD and I can't really understand the **Advection Equation** and **material derivative**.

Why material derivative equals zero?

Given 
\begin{equation}
 \begin{aligned}
  \nonumber\frac{\partial{q(t,\vec{x})}}{\partial{t}} &= \frac{\partial{q}}{\partial{t}} + \nabla q \cdot\frac{d\vec{x}}{dt}\\
  &= \frac{\partial{q}}{\partial{t}} + \nabla q \cdot\vec{u}\\
  &\equiv \frac{Dq}{Dt}
 \end{aligned}
 \end{equation}

and the Advection Equation

$$ \frac{Dq}{Dt} = 0 $$

At first I thought $\frac{\partial{q(t,\vec{x})}}{\partial{t}}$ is the change of $q$ at a fixed position $\vec{x}$ at time $t$, but if we set the material derivative to zero, the field would be static.

Then I realized that the value we want to know is $\frac{\partial{q}}{\partial{t}}$, which represents the change of $q$ at a fixed position $\vec{x}$ at time $t$. And $\nabla q$ is a known value from a function of $q$ with respect to position $\vec{x}$.

It is said that material derivative means the quantity is moving around but isn't changing in the Lagrangian viewpoint.

How to understand it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definition of material derivative:
\begin{equation}
\frac{Dq}{Dt} \equiv \frac{\partial{q}}{\partial{t}} + \nabla q \cdot \vec{u}
\end{equation}
Where $\vec{u}$ is the flow velocity ( for a fluid $\vec{u}=\frac{\vec{dx}}{dt}$ )

Start with continuity equation (with flux $ \ \ \vec{j}=(q\cdot\vec{u})\ \ $ for fluid ):
\begin{equation}
 \begin{aligned}
  0
&= \frac{\partial{q}}{\partial{t}} + \nabla \cdot (\vec{j})\\
&= \frac{\partial{q}}{\partial{t}} + \nabla \cdot (q\vec{u})\\
  &= \frac{\partial{q}}{\partial{t}} + \nabla q \cdot\vec{u} + q \nabla\cdot\vec{u}\\
 \end{aligned}
 \end{equation}
    for incompressible fluid $\nabla\cdot\vec{u}=0$ (so the last term disappears )  :
\begin{equation}
\frac{Dq}{Dt}= \frac{\partial{q}}{\partial{t}} + \nabla q \cdot \vec{u}=0
\end{equation}

Comment: So I can think material derivative  as the "generation of the quantity $q$"? (i.e. change of $q$ caused by "sink" or "source") Since within the fluid field there's no such "source" and "sink", the material derivative is thus zero?

Comment: Yes if you try to integrate over volume it is more clear: the first term is the change of quantity inside the volume, the last term is the change of quantity at the volume border.